# Why was Bellatrix living with the Malfoys?

Tags: harry-potter

I know she's in hiding. But can't she hide at her old house? And where is her husband? He's not dead, and I know that she didn't love him but I'd still expect them to be together. Lastly, by the ends of the books she not in hiding anymore, so if her house was originally unsafe, what to stop her going back now?

Comment: Bellatrix had a very close friendship with her sister Narcissa (Lucius's wife) so thats why she decided to hang out with her. That would be my best bet.

Comment: Voldemort chose the Malfoy's residence as his house and Belatrix just followed Voldemort.

Answer (score 10):

It appears that in the 7th book, Voldemort has taken over Malfoy Manor as the “headquarters” of the operation. So living at the Malfoys would be similar to living in Grimmauld Place like the Order of the Phoenix. Plus, it’s her sister’s house, so it’s not even like she’s staying with a stranger or a friend, it’s her own family. Also at this time the Malfoys are basically under house arrest, so she also may be acting as a kind of jailer as we see her following Narcissa around wherever she goes.

We also know from *The Cursed Child* that Bellatrix may have another reason for staying at Malfoy Manor:

> We find out that she is pregnant with Voldemort’s child during most of book 7, and having a safe space to stay while with child is a plus.

Comment: I do like the idea of her acting as a sort of jailer, keeping them in line. Although the Malfoys still act as though they have dominance at their house.

Comment: @Corvid yes they pretend, but in the scene were all the death eaters are gathered you see how they are very unhappy, as well as the scene where harry and co are there, again, the malfoys are like second class in their own house, but you got to give them credit for trying.

Comment: Yes, I've always liked the Malfoys and feel very sorry for them, I actuality think the rise of Voldemort was worse for them then anyone else. They had him watching over there shoulder almost constantly. I really don't think Lucius knew what he was sighing up for all those years ago, he must have been very young the as well.

Answer (score 6):

"But can't she hide at her old house?"

You just answered your own question. It's her old house - literally the first place anyone searching for her would look.

Afterwards, as has been commented, she just follows Voldemort wherever he goes. She's utterly obsessed with him; I doubt she values any other human life except him (and potentially Narcissa).

Comment: Voldemort = Human? Ummm...